# Join two files with out any common key

Tags: apache-pig

I have 2 input files The first file is having 2 columns and second file is having three column both have different values in it like

First file :
Type:
   (String)|(Integer)
Value:

```
City1|Value1
City2|Value2
City3|Value3
```

Second File:
Type:
    (String)|(String)|(Integer)
Value:

```
String1|Text1|Int1
String2|Text2|Int2
String3|Text3|Int3
```

I need Output as

```
Text1|City1|Value1
Text2|City2|Value2
Text3|City3|Value3
```

I can use any program skill to get this, If it is not possible in pig then i can go with other programs also. Please suggest me which one will be better and how to do that.

Please help me on this.Thanks in advance

Comment: general suggestion: pls try to give comprehensive examples. e.g. in above example, you could have gave values like Text1, Text2, Text3, City1|Value1, City2|Value2, City3|Value3. This would give better idea about what you are exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: pls mark the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not clear. If first relation has M values and second has N values, do you expect M*N values in results? Or do you expect M=N values in result

1. Assuming first (M*N values), you can use [CROSS](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#CROSS) operation.
2. Assuming second (M=N values), you can:
   a. Use [Enumerate](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.1.0/datafu/pig/bags/Enumerate.html) on both the relations to add numbers (unique enumerator number) to each tuples.
   b. Then join on the enumerator number to make sure 1st row from both relation joins, then 2nd row and so on.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't join without a common key in Pig. Try using concat function for your usecase